# Firefox not representing hr correctly

Tags: html, css

i have a code which should represent output in format,

```
_____________________________
|                            |
|____________________________|
Insert

  __________________________

Poster                    Date
--------------POST------------
    Comm. ________________
    Comm. ________________

  ___________________________

Poster                    Date
--------------POST------------
    Comm. ________________
    Comm. ________________
```

Now, my code is working properly in chrome and even internet explorer. But firefox is not accepting my code for this format.

```
_____________________________
|                            |
|____________________________|
Insert

  __________________________

Poster                    Date       ___________________________
--------------POST------------
    Comm. ________________
    Comm. ________________



Poster                    Date
--------------POST------------
    Comm. ________________
    Comm. ________________
```

I am on this for hours with no result. Any fix? 
Here is the fiddle. Here in case there is no hr tag showing in page, http://jsfiddle.net/JA8TS/

Comment: Smells like floating issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to clear your floating elements, add this line

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

After these lines

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Comment " class="button" style="font-size:1em;width:100px;float:right;margin-top:4px;"/>
            </div>
        </form>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JA8TS/1/)

Note: Didn't made the form fancy, as `smarty` is spoiling the form here

Comment: @user2207792 You welcome :) and btw your code is lil ugly, if you've rights to change it, do refactor it out

Comment: @alien, thanks for feedback. Can you please explain how to tidy my code.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use `<br>` split your lines by `<p></p>` which will force new lines.

Edit:

I say split your lines, I mean encapsulate them in `<p></p>`.

```
<p>Line 1</p>
<p>Line 2</p>
```

Rather than:

```
Line 1<br>
Line 2
```